# How to define OR condition in Clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I'm new to Clingo.

I want to know how to express an OR condition inside a count aggregate.

I'm writing this rule.

```
countPreviousSlots(C1, C2, TotalCount) :-
    firstLecture(C2, S2, G2, I2),
    TotalCount = #count{S1,G1,I1 : slot(S1, G1, I1, C1), (S1 < S2; (S1==S2, G1 < G2); (S1==S2, G1==G2, I1 < I2))},
    slot(_, _, _, _, C1).
```

But the round brackets aren't admitted by clingo. How do I have to to formulate this condition in clingo?

And what's the difference if I move the condition and I write:

```
countPreviousSlots(C1, C2, TotalCount) :-
    firstLecture(C2, S2, G2, I2),
    TotalCount = #count{S1,G1,I1 : slot(S1, G1, I1, C1)},
    slot(_, _, _, _, C1), (S1 < S2; (S1==S2, G1 < G2); (S1==S2, G1==G2, I1 < I2)).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formulate the lexicographic ordering with a further predicate. Disjunction can be nicely described with multiple rules with the same head. Here is a possible example

```
num(1..2).

lexorder(X1, X2, Y1, Y2) :-
  num(X1),
  num(X2),
  num(Y1),
  num(Y2),
  X1 < Y1.

lexorder(X1, X2, Y1, Y2) :-
  num(X1),
  num(X2),
  num(Y1),
  num(Y2),
  X1 = Y1,
  X2 < Y2.
```

The difference is that you count differently. The set you are creating in the first version {...} is smaller than in the second version as it has less constraints. Moreover, in the second version, some variables are not bounded (S1) such that the grounder will not know how to replace S1 with an atom. The variables inside the count statement are scoped between the brackets.

Comment: I tried to add it to my code with 6 arguments, but clingo stops to "reading" and never go to the "solving" state. But if I use the same rule with 4 arguments, it's fine. Do you know why it happens? There is a limit of arguments per rule?

Comment: clingo consists of two stages: First it grounds your program, i.e. it replaces the variables with all reasonable instantiations. Then, it solves the ground logic program. This means that in your case the lexorder predicate generates too many ground rules. If possible, try to restrict it by reformulating your program. This is usually the creative part of declaraitve problem solving :-) Another approach is to use extended versions of clingo, such as clingo[DL] (difference logic)